# Envío Email con python. Destinatarios no ocultos

Tags: python, email

Estoy enviando un email en python a varios destinatarios, el problema es que las personas que lo reciben no ven a quien se le ha enviado el email y lo necesito ya que uno de ellos siempre tiene que darle a responder a todos.

La Lista de destinatarios va cambiando según unos parámetros, con lo cual la opción de que el resto sepa a quien tiene que responder no es una opción.

He probado con ejemplos de internet básicos y me pasa igual.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib

from = 'username@gmail.com'
to  = ['destinatario1@gmail.com', 'destinatario2@gmail.com']
msg = 'Correo enviado utilizando Python + smtplib'


# Datos
username = 'username@gmail.com'
password = 'Contraseña'

# Enviando el correo
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(from, to, msg)
server.quit()
```

Alguien sabe como hacer para que los que lo reciben les salga todos los destinatarios.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Buenas! Estas seguro que este ejemplo funciona? Revisa el **from** del código.

Comment: Deberías de buscar la manera de meter todos los correos en el CC de la cabecera. De esa forma mandas el correo a uno y los demás reciben una copia

Comment: En [otra pregunta de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546435/1264820) (en inglés) tienes la solución

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, el código funciona, pero efectivamente. Falta en el mensaje la cabecera . Al servidor smtp solo le importa el mensaje como tal y no lo que ponga en un método de python, aunque para este caso al no tenerlos en el mensaje, el método parece incorporarlos, pero como copia oculta.

Answer (score 1):

La solución para el ejemplo es la siguiente por si le puede valer a alguien mas.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

remitente = 'username@gmail.com'
destinatario  = ['destinatario1@gmail.com', 'destinatario2@gmail.com']
asunto = 'Prueba de envío desde Python'
msg = 'Correo enviado utilizando Python + smtplib'

mensaje = MIMEMultipart()

mensaje['From'] = remitente
mensaje['To'] = ", ".join(destinatario)
mensaje['Subject'] = asunto

mensaje.attach(MIMEText(msg, 'plain'))

# Datos
username = 'username@gmail.com'
password = 'Contraseña'

# Enviando el correo
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(remitente, destinatario, mensaje.as_string())
server.quit()
```